# 段の数と表示する記号を引数とした関数を使って三角形を表示したい。

Tags: c

三角形を作りたいのですが、１８行目あたりでエラーが出ます。

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
identifier expected
```

**ソースコード:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void putTri(int size, char mark)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            printf("%c", mark);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    int size;
    char mark;
    
    putTri(3, #);
    putTri(5, ?);
    putTri(5, ~);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`putTri(3, #);` の中に間違いがあるようです。 `putTri(5, '#');` の書き方を使えれば、コンパイルができます。